# Add a header to the UITableView programatically using swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a header to the table view which is a `NSLocalized String`. I  tried doing this ,

```
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = NSLocalizedString("title", comment : "") as? UIView
```

But an error appeared that "Cast from type `String` to unrelated type `UIView` always fails". I tried without type casting as well and then the error was "Cannot convert type 'String' to the type `UIView` ". can anyone help me in adding this header to the `tableView` ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift

Comment: You are trying to set the tableHeaderView which is the topView before the tableView starts. Do you want to set the tableView section header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the view not string.

You can set label in view and set that view in table header.

```
var view1: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600));
var label: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600))
view1.addSubview(label);
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view1;
```

Comment: I ain't doing it programatically , So what you meant was I should declare a UILabel , and set the text of that label to this string and then set this label to the view ? Did I understand correctly ?

Comment: I am * doing it programatically !

Comment: Yes, you can add label in view with add programatically.

        var view1: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600));
        var label: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600))
        view1.addSubview(label);

Comment: Yups its like that, because tableHeader need UIView class to display table header. and it will appear in Top of table.